# Align multiple steps of system of equations

Tags: alignment

I try to write a system of linear equations by this format in Jupyter Notebook that not support   `\systeme` , I can do the first block that contains equation in both sides by

```
\begin{align*}
\left\{
    \begin{alignedat}{5}
     \color{green} x& {}\color{green}{+}{} & \color{green}{2y}& {}\color{green}+{} & \color{green}{3z} & \color{green}{=} &\color{green}{6} \\
     2x& {}-{} & 3y& {}+{} & 2z & = &14 \\
     3x& {}+{} & y& {}-{} & z  & = &-2
    \end{alignedat}
\right . \xrightarrow{\text{multiply first by -3}}
    \left\{
    \begin{alignedat}{5}
     \color{green} {-3x}& {}\color{green}{+}{} & \color{green}{-6y}& {}\color{green}-{} & \color{green}{9z} & \color{green}{=} &\color{green}{-18} \\
     2x& {}-{} & 3y& {}+{} & 2z & = &14 \\
     3x& {}+{} & y& {}-{} & z  & = &-2
    \end{alignedat}
\\ 
\\
\left\{
    \begin{alignedat}{5}
     {}& {}{}{} & {}{}{} & {} & {} {} \\
     \\
     \\
    \end{alignedat}
  \right . \xrightarrow{\text{multiply first by -3}}    
\right .  
\left\{
\begin{alignedat}{5}
     \color{green} {-3x}& {}\color{green}{+}{} & \color{green}{-6y}& {}\color{green}-{} & \color{green}{9z} & \color{green}{=} &\color{green}{-18} \\
     2x& {}-{} & 3y& {}+{} & 2z & = &14 \\
     3x& {}+{} & y& {}-{} & z  & = &-2
    \end{alignedat}
\right . 
\end{align*}
```

But I have no idea how to aligned other blocks.

[image: Sample of the the]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: What do the blue vertical lines signify?

Comment: The lines for just to explain the alignments that I want. :)

Answer (score 2):

The code and the screenshot you've posted do not appear to have much in common. The following solution takes some of your code in row 1, but switches to the material in the screenshot for the next two rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,xcolor}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}}

\newcommand\myarray[1]{%
   \begingroup
   \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.33}
   \setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
   \left\{ 
   \begin{array}{ rCrCrCr }
   #1
   \end{array}\right.
   \endgroup}
\newcommand\cgr{\color{green}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
&\myarray{%
     \cgr x &\cgr + &\cgr 2y &\cgr + &\cgr 3z &\cgr = &\cgr 6 \\
         2x &     - &     3y &     + &     2z &     = &    14 \\
         3x &     + &      y &     - &      z &     = &    -2 }
&\quad &\xrightarrow{\text{multiply first by $-3$}} &\quad
&\myarray{%
     \cgr -3x &\cgr - &\cgr 6y &\cgr - &\cgr 9z &\cgr = &\cgr -18 \\
           2x &     - &     3y &     + &     2z &     = &      14 \\
           3x &     + &      y &     - &      z &     = &      -2 }
\\
&&&\xrightarrow{\text{2nd}=\text{2nd}-2\times\text{1st}} &
&\myarray{%
     x & + & 2y & + & 3z & = & 6 \\
       & - & 7y & - & 4z & = & 2 \\
    3x & + &  y & - &  z & = &-2 }
\\
&&&\xrightarrow{\text{3rd}=\text{3rd}-3\times\text{1st}} &
&\myarray{%
     x & + & 2y & + &  3z & = &   6 \\
       & - & 7y & - &  4z & = &   2 \\
       & - & 5y & - & 10z & = & -20 }
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but seem like the  ``\systeme`` is not available in Jupyter Notebook so I did not use that in the first place.

Comment: @RayRonnaret - I'm not sure I understand your comment -- my answer does *not* use `\systeme`. And there's a very good reason why I didn't use `\systeme`: It doesn't allow individual rows to be colored. I take it that being able to color rows (or even individual variables) is an important requirement of yours.

Comment: sorry, what I should say is, the Jupyter notebook not allow packages or new command.

Comment: @RayRonnaret - Your claim that "the Jupyter notebook [does] not allow packages or new command[s]" doesn't sound right. After all, the `align*` and `alignedat` environment and the `\text` macro are not part of the LaTeX kernel but are, instead, provided by the external `amsmath` package.

Comment: I did try your suggested code, but it not work. I have no idea for the background but I believe Jupyter notebook not recognize some tags such user define or some package for example ``\systeme`` and also ``\usepackage`` and ``\newcommand``. I sorry I make thing wrong.

I just try letex for weeks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need colour for the first equations, you have a simple solution with a single alignment point and the help of the `systeme` and `eqparbox` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[1]{$\scriptstyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}


\systeme{x + 2y + 3z = 6, 2x - 3y + 2z = 14, 3x + y - z = -2 }
      & \xrightarrow[\eqmathbox{\scriptstyle\text{line 3}\leftarrow \text{line 3} -3\,\text{line 1}}]{\text{line 2}\leftarrow \text{line 2}- 2\,\text{line 1}}
       \systeme{x + 2y+ 3z = 6, -7y - 4z = 2, -5y - 10z = -20} \\
     & \xrightarrow{\eqmathbox{\text{line 3}\leftarrow \text{line 3}\div -5}}
       \systeme{x + 2y+ 3z = 6, -7y - 4z = 2, y + 2z = 4} \\
     & \xrightarrow{\eqmathbox{\text{line 2}\leftrightarrow \text{line 3}}}
       \systeme{x + 2y+ 3z = 6, y + 2z = 4, -7y - 4z = 2} \\
     & \xrightarrow[]{\eqmathbox{\text{line 3}\leftrightarrow \text{line 3} + 7\,\text{line}2}}
       \systeme{x + 2y+ 3z = 6, y + 2z = 4, 10z = 30}
    \end{align*}

 \end{document}
```

}
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but seem like the  ``\systeme`` is not available in Jupyter Notebook so I did not use that in the first place.

Comment: @RayRonnaret: As I don't know Jupyter Notebook, I supposed it was based on a LaTeX distribution and possibly that you could use a local TeXMF root to add any missing packages.

Answer (score 0):

I try to make it but will appreciate if there is the better ways. Here is not a nice but possible in Jupyter.

```
**Example 5.2** 
$$
\begin{gather*}
\left\{
    \begin{alignedat}{7}
      x&  {}+{} & 2y& {}+{} & 3z& = &6 \\
     2x&  {}-{} & 3y& {}+{} & 2z& = &14 \\
     3x&  {}+{} &  y& {}-{} & z& = &-2
    \end{alignedat}
\right . \xrightarrow{(2) = (2) - 2 \times (1)} 
    \left\{
    \begin{alignedat}{7}
      x& {}+{} & 2y& {}+{} & 3z & = &6 \\
       & {}-{} & 7y& {}-{} & 4z & = &2 \\
     3x& {}+{} &  y& {}-{} & z  & = &-2
    \end{alignedat}
\\ 
\\
\begin{alignedat}{7}
 \quad& \quad & \quad& \quad & \quad & \quad &\qquad  \\
     \\
     \\
\end{alignedat}
\right . \xrightarrow{(3) = (3) - 3 \times (1)}    
\left\{
\begin{alignedat}{7}     
     x& {}+{} & 2y& {}+{} & 3z & = &6 \\
      & {}-{}  & 7y& {}-{} & 4z & = &2 \\
      & {}-{}  & 5y& {}-{} & 10z& = &-20
    \end{alignedat}
\right . 
\\
\begin{alignedat}{7}
 \quad& \quad & \quad& \quad & \quad & \quad &\qquad  \\
     \\
     \\
\end{alignedat}
\xrightarrow{\quad(2) \leftrightarrow (3)\quad} 
\left\{
\begin{alignedat}{7}     
     x& {}+{} & 2y& {}+{} & 3z  & = &6 \\
      & {}-{} & 5y& {}-{} & 10z & = &-20 \\
      & {}-{} & 7y& {}-{} & 4z  & = &2
    \end{alignedat}
\right .
\\
\begin{alignedat}{7}
 \quad& \quad & \quad& \quad & \quad & \quad &\;  \\
     \\
     \\
\end{alignedat}
\xrightarrow{\;(2)=(2)\div -5\quad} 
\left\{
\begin{alignedat}{7}     
     x& {}+{}&  2y& {}+{} &  3z  & = &6 \\
      & {}{}{}&  y& {}+{} &  2z  & = &4 \\
      & {}-{}&  7y& {}-{} &  4z  & = &2
    \end{alignedat}
\right .
\\
\begin{alignedat}{7}
 \quad& \quad & \quad& \quad & \quad & \quad &\;  \\
     \\
     \\
\end{alignedat}
\xrightarrow{\;(3)=(3) + 7 \times (2) \quad} 
\left\{
\begin{alignedat}{7}     
     x& {}+{}&  2y& {}+{} &  3z  & = &6 \\
      & {}{}{}&  y& {}+{} &  2z  & = &4 \\
      & {}{}{}&  {}& {}{}{} &  10z  & = &30
    \end{alignedat}
\right .
\end{gather*}
$$
```

[image: Mine out put in Jupyter]